# Configuring MetaData fields in Word 2016

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-outlook-2016, microsoft-word-2016, skype-for-business

The template I have made has the "Author" field however our Word accounts are synced with our Global "Outlook Contact" so when the person is signed opens it, they pull in the Email address instead of the name.  Is there a way in the template to make it so it pulls just the name.  Also since it can pull information from Global is there a way to have it also pull in the "authors" phone number and fax number?

Comment: How did you made your "Author" field? Under File > Info > Properties? It is usually displayed with account name (not email address) that you used to sign in Office in File > Account.

Comment: Hi WinniL, the "Author" field auto populates with our email since our Exchange appears to be connected through Skype for Business with Word.  So when you type your name in Author it pulls the user email. Not sure how it is though.